# Jquery radio button focus not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

Hello everyone I'm doing some custom radio buttons styles and the css :focus do not work. So I'm figuring out some js solutions and right now I have this:

```
// Focuse radio btn
  function focus() {
   $('.radio, .field-label').focusin(function(e) {
   //console.log(e.target);
   $(e.target).parent().animate({opacity: .5},400);
});

$('.radio, .field-label').focusout(function(e) {
  //console.log('focus out!');
  $('.radio, .field-label').parent().animate({opacity: 1},1000);
});
}

focus();
```

This is working on Chrome. But in the other browser like safari or mozilla it doesn't work. Why? Any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function focus() {
    $(document).on('focus', '.radio, .field-label', function(e) {
       //console.log(e.target);
       $(this).parent().animate({opacity: .5},400);
    });

    $(document).on('focusout', '.radio, .field-label', function(e) {
      //console.log('focus out!');
      $(this).parent().animate({opacity: 1},1000);
    });
}

focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with simple CSS? In this way you style a label which is located immediately after a checked radio button

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label { 
  color: red; 
  font-size: 60px;  
}
```

```html
<input id="radio1" type="radio"><label for="radio1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio"><label for="radio2">Radio 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine in FF and Chrome:

```
$(document).on('focusin', '.radio, .field-label', function() {
  $(this).parent().animate({
    opacity: .5
  }, 400);
});

$(document).on('focusout', '.radio, .field-label', function() {
  $(this).parent().animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kdvtda61/)